# Approach alternative to subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing this at the moment but would like the good guys of SO to look at it. It works but I think using sub-query/nested queries will be much faster but still learning MySQL queries

A nested/subquery approach would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
//////
//Get Events

$query_display_events  = "SELECT E.id, E.er_mem_id, E.er_ev_name, E.er_ev_status FROM ".ER_EVENTS_MAIN." E WHERE E.er_ev_status=1 AND E.er_mem_id = '$user_id'";


$e_result = mysql_query($query_display_events) or die(header("Location: /er_error_page?error_msg=1"));

// print table
$data = '<table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bord_display_events">
<th>Event Name <th>Description<th>Starts<th>Ends<th>Status

';


while($e_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($e_result)) {


    //Get Events Time

$query_get_ev_time  = "SELECT T.er_ev_id, T.er_ev_start_date, T.er_ev_end_date FROM ".ER_EVENTS_TIME." T WHERE T.er_ev_id = '$e_row[id]'";


$t_result = mysql_query($query_get_ev_time) or die(header("Location: /er_error_page?error_msg=1"));
    while($t_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($t_result)) {

                    //Format date
                    $ev_start_time = date('Y-m-d g:i a', $t_row['er_ev_start_date']); 
                    $ev_end_time = date('Y-m-d g:i a', $t_row['er_ev_end_date']);


  $data .= "\n<tr>
              \n\t<td><b><a href=/readnews/$e_row[id]> $e_row[er_ev_name]</a></b>
              <td><font class=font_news_display_body>".mb_wordwrap(substr($e_row['er_ev_name'],0,170))."..."."
              <td><font class=font_news_display_body>$ev_start_time
              <td><font class=font_news_display_body>$ev_end_time

      \n</tr>
      ";

  }
}
$data .= "\n</table>\n";
////////
```

Comment: What's your question? Or do you just want someone to completely rewrite your code?

Comment: Why the down vote? Could you please explain why you downvoted? Jk

Comment: `please include table schema`, for question related to SQL tuning, PHP code is superfluous, you should include the execution plan instead of copy and paste from your existing source code

Comment: I did something which from research appears not to be the best and I am asking for others to help. Is that a crime?

Comment: if you think you can rewrite the code and point me in the right directions then fine. If not, I don't think I have committed a crime by asking. From the code it's very easy to see the table schema. Very easy and I think it's the least of the problems for anyone that is willing to help. Thanks

Comment: SO is not what you think it is.

Comment: example of better question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914501/mysql-query-with-sum-is-not-returning-the-expected-results (better readability, and why your question is related to PHP?)

Comment: Make we hear word abeg. Those that posted answers are not less human or less intelligent than you. Always have that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT E.id, E.er_mem_id, E.er_ev_name, E.er_ev_status, 
       T.er_ev_id, T.er_ev_start_date, T.er_ev_end_date 
    FROM ER_EVENTS_MAIN E 
        INNER JOIN ER_EVENTS_TIME T 
            ON E.id = T.er_ev_id
    WHERE E.er_ev_status = 1 
        AND E.er_mem_id = '$user_id'
```

Comment: Now great guys are talking... Thanks. Will try it out and revert. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a LEFT JOIN on the table?

```
SELECT T.er_ev_id, T.er_ev_start_date, T.er_ev_end_date FROM `T` LEFT JOIN `E` ON (`T`.`er_ev_id`=`E`.`er_ev_id`) WHERE `T.er_ev_id`='something'
```

Sorry, the query itself might not be correct for your table layout. You might just wanna read up on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

You also have different kinds of joins (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, etc) which bring different conditions about the joined table with them ;-)